# How many iterations are necessary to reduce error in the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel method?

Tags: numerical-methods

I reedited the question:

We want to use Jacobi method to solve the following system:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\pi^2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & \pi^2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & \pi^2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & \pi^2
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Be $x^{(*)}$ the solution of the system. Use the estimative

$$
||x^{(k)} - x^{(*)}||_\infty \leq \frac{\sigma^k}{1-\sigma}||x^{(1)}-x^{(0)}||_\infty
$$

to get the number of iterations needed to obtain an error less than $\epsilon = 10^{-8}$, beginning at

\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: The problem statement is ill posed. What do you mean by converges, what norm? What type of error do you mean? Also, the short answer is: in general, you won't know exactly. *Sometimes* you can give an upper bound if your problem is small and/or your relaxation update matrices are nice.

Comment: I restated the question. Does it make sense?

Comment: Have you calculated $σ$ and $x^{(1)}$ to evaluate the right side of the estimate? That is what I would try first, since it is the only information / estimate provided.